# Python: is the system function too slow?

Tags: python, http, networking, flask

I have a small network with 3 computers. I have a C++ program on the 2nd computer that reads packets from a network interface while the first computer sends it data. I need to run that from the third computer. I wrote a small python script using `flask`

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    os.system("./a.out &")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The problem is, there seems to be a small delay while starting the executable using `os.system()` and the second computer misses some packets. Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend the use of a queue of some sort. The performance of a high level Web server calling a system function can be unpredictable (based on how busy the machine is etc).

If you had a process reading in the background doing the communication and queuing the packets and the Web endpoint reads from the queue, would be the most reliable solution.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. The webserver does maintain a queue of it's own internally. Do you mean that I should have a queue in my Python script? How will that help?